# Side menu drawer returns self.navigationController as nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

I want to push `UIViewController` on my `NavigationController` but when  try to do it it says that `NavigationController` is nil. and hence i'm not able to push any view controllers on the stack. Although i can push more view controllers by clicking any button present already on the stack (The issue is only with the side drawer).

Here's what I did

On an empty storyboard I took a navigation controller and set its custom class as "My Custom Navigation Controller (It has the side menu layout)" which extends Navigation Controller.
The root view controller of this navigation controller is my "Home screen view Controller"
When i try to

```
po self.navigationController
```

it returns nil

What can I do?

Comment: can you show your storyboard structure ?

Comment: Please Check your Root controller  When you push it  and also Please add your Source Code for understanding.